# how to add image for headers in navigationdrawer in android

Tags: java, android, json

Hi in the below code in my project contains navigation drawer with expandable listview.
but everything was working fine. but want to display image for headers on leftside and arrow icon should be in right side for each header.

using json am parsing the data and in the same way want to display images for headers.

can any one help me how to do that one.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Model_country> al_main = new ArrayList<>();
    ExpandableListView ev_list;
    CountryAdapter obj_adapter;
    String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    HomeFragment fragment;
    TextView tv_name;
    RelativeLayout rl_menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fn_data();
        init();

    }

    private void init() {

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ev_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ev_menu);
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        rl_menu = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_menu);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        obj_adapter = new CountryAdapter(MainActivity.this, al_main);
        ev_list.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        ev_list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });

        setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ev_list);

        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", al_main.get(0).getStr_country());
        bundle.putString("des", al_main.get(0).getAl_state().get(0).getStr_description());
        bundle.putString("dish", al_main.get(0).getAl_state().get(0).getStr_name());
        bundle.putString("image", al_main.get(0).getAl_state().get(0).getStr_image());
        tv_name.setText(al_main.get(0).getStr_country());

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "HomeFragment").addToBackStack("null").commit();


        rl_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                    || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            listView);
                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
       /* if (height < 10)
            height = 200;*/
        params.height = height;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }

    private void fn_data() {

        String str_data = loadJSONFromAsset();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject_country = new JSONObject(str_data);
            JSONArray jsonArray_country = jsonObject_country.getJSONArray("country");
            al_main = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_country.length(); i++) {
                Model_country obj_country = new Model_country();
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_country.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray jsonArray_dishes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dishes");
                ArrayList<Model_Dish> al_dishes = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray_dishes.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject_dishes = jsonArray_dishes.getJSONObject(j);
                    Model_Dish obj_dish = new Model_Dish();
                    obj_dish.setStr_name(jsonObject_dishes.getString("dishname"));
                    obj_dish.setStr_description(jsonObject_dishes.getString("description"));
                    obj_dish.setStr_image(jsonObject_dishes.getString("image"));
                    al_dishes.add(obj_dish);
                }

                obj_country.setAl_state(al_dishes);
                obj_country.setStr_country(jsonObject.getString("name"));
               // obj_country.setStr_country (jsonObject.getString("image"));

                al_main.add(obj_country);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ExpandableListView expandableListView) {
        CountryAdapter adapter = (CountryAdapter) expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = expandableListView.getPaddingTop() + expandableListView.getPaddingBottom();
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = adapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, expandableListView);
            groupItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = adapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null, expandableListView);
                    listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    listItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec
                            .makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = expandableListView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight + expandableListView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getGroupCount() - 1);

        if (height < 10)
            height = 100;
        params.height = height;
        expandableListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        expandableListView.requestLayout();
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("dishes.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Json response " + json);
        return json;

    }

    public void fn_selectedPosition(int group, int child) {

        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", al_main.get(group).getStr_country());
        bundle.putString("des", al_main.get(group).getAl_state().get(child).getStr_description());
        bundle.putString("dish", al_main.get(group).getAl_state().get(child).getStr_name());
        bundle.putString("image", al_main.get(group).getAl_state().get(child).getStr_image());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "HomeFragment").addToBackStack("null").commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

        tv_name.setText(al_main.get(group).getStr_country());
    }
```

activity_main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#234E6F"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl_menu"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <include layout="@layout/menu_layout"></include>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expandable listview for this. use custom adapter which will have textview and imageview. set image and text using expandable listview adapter. you can use custom adapter for child and parent both

```
  public View getGroupView(final int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null)
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_comment, viewGroup, false);
        TextView username=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);

                    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_hifi)).setImageResource(R.drawable.high_5_icon_highlited);

    }


 @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null)
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_comment, viewGroup, false);

       view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName)).setText(getChild(i, i1).getUser_name() + "   ");
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: can you give some example